# Unable to upload file (image n vdo) to blob storage, getting error: mandatory header missing "x-ms-blob-type"

Tags: azure, upload, header, blob, required

I'm trying to upload an image to azure blob storage, 2 days ago the code was working perfectly but recently I am getting the error that a mandatory request header is missing.
Following is the error returned:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Error><Code>MissingRequiredHeader</Code><Message>An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified.\nRequestId:93cefc02-45af-41b0-9cb5-649d485faa49\nTime:2012-10-03T09:05:58.1982699Z</Message><HeaderName>x-ms-blob-type</HeaderName></Error>"
```

Let me explain the program flow. I am using a nodejs server to create a SAS from azure. This sas  is then used by windows 8 client to PUT the specific file onto the blob storage.

```
 function uploadFileAsync(uploadURL, file) {
        return new WinJS.Promise(function (complete, error, progress) {
            file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.read).then(function (stream) {

                makeBlob(file.contentType, stream).then(function (blob) {
                    WinJS.xhr({ url: uploadURL, type: "PUT", data: blob, headers: { "Content-type":
             file.contentType} }).then(function (res) {
                        complete(res);
                    }, function (err) {
                        error(err);
                    });
                });
            });
        });

    }

 function makeBlob(contentType, stream) {
        return new WinJS.Promise(function (c, e) {
            var blob = window.MSApp.createBlobFromRandomAccessStream(contentType, stream);
                c(blob);
        });
    }
```

uploadURL is the SAS from node server.

I tried adding another header `"x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob"` with the PUT request, but alas no use!!

```
WinJS.xhr({ url: uploadURL, type: "PUT", data: blob, headers: { "Content-type":
file.contentType,  "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob" } }).then(function (res) {
```

My team and I have tried uploading it from a number of installations, using the most basic (oldest) versions of our application which were working perfectly before. From this we concluded that something must have change on the azure level. Please advise!

UPDATE:
Finally got it working again, adding the header x-ms-blob-type did the trick this time.
Fiddler was indeed a big help, thanks Gaurav...

However using Fiddler revealed some things to me which are still unclear.

1) Following is the request and response captured by the fiddler

```
Request:
PUT /dummy/Content/dummy.bmp?st=2012-10-06T06%3A53%3A49Z&se=2012-10-06T07%3A53%3A49Z&sr=dummy&sig=dummydummyNQ4%3D HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Filename: dummy.bmp
Content-Type: image/bmp
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
Method: PUT
UA-CPU: AMD64
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; Trident/6.0)
Host: dummy.blob.core.windows.net
Content-Length: 85414
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

Response:
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-MD5: MdRpPr+eOePkjry2+6myQg==
Last-Modified: Sat, 06 Oct 2012 06:57:45 GMT
ETag: "dummyTag"
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: dummyide-f2defa18c095
x-ms-version: 2011-08-18
```

Shouldn't the serviceVersion be 2012-02-12, because i haven't specified it anywhere. So shouldn't it default to the latest.

2) According to this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179451.aspx
x-ms-blob-type is an optional header then why is it saying its mandatory?

PS: Adding all the REQUIRED headers didnt help. It still said Mandatory Header Missing (x-ms-blob-type).

Comment: See also http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/f6245ac3-f9e3-41fe-b40f-a669d4511bbe (duplicate question on MSDN).

Answer (score 0):

Even though it worked for you 2 days ago, could you try adding the required headers [from this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179451.aspx) (like **x-ms-date** fro example).

Answer (score 0):

I hit here looking for way to get a blob or File out of the StorageFile object. your makeblob function gave a lead to me. thanks.

I suggest an alternative for makeblob function.

```
function makeblob(storageFile)
{
    return MSApp.createFileFromStorageFile(storageFile);
}
```

call site also need to change little bit and call to file.OpenAsync can be removed.

regards the PUT blob api call -

1. suggest to explicit put x-ms-version header
2. is your sas client doing the other stuff of putting sharedkey authorization header etc.
   or is it public blob?
3. I am also solving similar problem - win8 client, nodejs server, uploading images to azure storage. currently, I got direct upload to the azure blob working. I am exploring using
   shared access signature to see if win8 client can directly talk to put blob api, and not go thru nodejs server (save some load on the nodejs server). not thru with the investigation yet.

HTH.